# How to change Facebook meta tags dynamically in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-like

I have a resources.aspx page that renders on run-time displaying all the articles (a title, description, image, and a read more link) with each of the article displayed. I have successfully been able to render social media buttons (Facebook's Like, Twitter's Tweet, LinkedIn's Inshare, and Google's G+) on in each of my rendered div's. Now, the problem is that when I click on Facebook's like button, it post just the URL of my page to my timeline. I want it to post the title of the article, it's image, and some description set by me. How can I get it done using Open Graph meta tags? I'm unable to change their values on run-time.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a tautology, but because Facebook uses the meta tags to decide the title, description, etc, If you're not able to change the meta tag values at runtime, you're not going to be able to change the title, description at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the question.  If so please edit your question to clarify.

Why can't you change their values at runtime?  What specific features of ASP.NET are you using that would preclude setting meta tag values at runtime?  Does Facebook just see your resources.aspx file as the URL or do each of your articles get their own URL?

Razor:
`<meta property="og:description" content="@Model.YourCustomDescription"/>`